# Where should 'The' come in this sentence and where it should not?

Tags: articles

The following is the title of a survey form

*A Study on **the** Safety and Welfare Measures taken by **the** Municipality for **the** Scavengers*

there are three 'the's in above sentence. are all the three of them necessary? or is there any 'the' that is unnecessarily used?

safety and welfare measures are specific to each municipality. so, they are  ***The*** safety and welfare measures

the municipality in the conversation belongs to my hometown. so, it is ***The*** Municipality

the scavengers work for that municipality office. so, they are ***the*** scavengers

Am I correct? please help.

Comment: Yes, all are appropriate.

Comment: All 3 instances look fine. However, if the Scavengers is a role rather than a specific group of people, drop the last *the*. You might want to say something like "regarding Scavengers" instead of "for the Scavengers".

Comment: If you're learning English, there's also a sister site to EL&U called [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) that you might like to visit. While composing this comment, I noticed that someone (not me) down-voted your question. This might be due to the slightly different emphases of EL&U and ELL. EL&U tends to be treated as a Q&A for questions that a native speaker might ask, whereas ELL is designed for questions that learners ask. (Yes, there's a lot of overlap.) You're welcome to post questions to either site, especially with the effort you show in constructing them.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am an Indian, learning English. I didn't know about the existence of ELL. Thank you for suggesting. I just joined in it. But, I don't find any down votes here...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. You have pretty much answered your own question. Because of the specificity of 'safety and welfare measures', 'municipality' and 'scavengers', the three 'the's are fine.